# I am unable to install pytorch 1.7.1 using pip,conda

Tags: pip, pytorch, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am unable to install pytorch 1.7.1 using pip & conda statements given in pytorch's official website

I need pytorch 1.7.1 and torchaudio 0.7.2 for a project, i tired installing it using the commands given in pytorch's official website

my environment : ubuntu 22.10

minioconda3

python : 3.10.10

pip : pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

I am getting an error stating there is no matching distribution for torch==1.7.1, tried using pip3 install got the same error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDhK1.png)

conda :
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cpuonly -c pytorch

I am getting an error stating that the packages are not not avilable in the channels,Getting the sam error after using conda-forge also
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLSgk.png)

Answer (score 1):

turns out pytorch does not support python versions > 3.9
worked as intended after downgrading to python 3.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).